# How I can identify an unpublished post on Facebook page RTU?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I'm working with the Real-Time Updates for pages, and RTU is sending me updates almost correctly... RTU is also sending unpublished **link** posts...

Since RTU is watching for "visible" updates on the page, and RTU is not sending the others unpublished posts types (video, photo, status) until the user or a schedule publish it, I think that it is a bug...

But, as a workaround, I need to identify and ignore these, and the JSON sent for me is not helping too much:

```
{
    "id": "113343148850749",
    "time": "1435939768",
    "changes": [
        {
            "field": "feed",
            "value": {
                "item": "share",
                "verb": "add",
                "share_id": "427254334126294",
                "post_id": "113343148850749_427254334126294",
                "sender_id": "113343148850749",
                "message": "TenhaosmelhoresprodutosTRES®nasuaEmpresa.ComprenossoComboOfficecomumDescontoEspecial.",
                "link": "http://loja.escolhatres.com.br/combo_office?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=darkpost&utm_content=office&utm_campaign=office_facebook",
                "sender_name": "TRES"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think you might have to request the details of the post via API – looking at it in GAE I see that it has `is_hidden: true`. // If you think this is a bug, you should file a report, https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: Yeah, this field might work for unpublished posts... There is a bug report to facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1627053657511475/), but we got no responses yet, and I need a faster solution. Thank you!